# TV show, late 70s or early 80s: Man with a machine to observe and/or travel to the Moon/Mars

Tags: story-identification, tv

I am looking for a TV show with the intended main audience probably being either children or young youths.

Main plot was a man with a machine/device either trying to observe or travel to the Moon and/or Mars. The machine was very large and shaking like crazy, and it did break I think. The show kind of intended to create interest in technical stuff and science.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: thx, was giving as much input as possible cause I was maybe 3 or 4 years when I watched it. asked my mom and she remembers the show but not its name but confirmed my personal assessment of its purpose and plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I think of is [*Salvage 1*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078681/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) - the main character (Sheriff Andy Taylor from Mayberry (wait, no, Matlock (actually Harry Broderick, but played by Andy Griffith))) owns a junkyard/salvage operation, and actually builds a rocket (out of salvage - the main parts are a cement mixer and a Texaco gas truck) and travels to the moon to salvage the stuff that was left there in the pilot. They find repeated reasons to re-use their spaceship (note that this was before the U.S. space shuttle program was up and running) for an entire season in 1979.

However, this was a prime-time TV show at the time, so not really aimed at kids explicitly. That said, I can't say it's impossible that it would *feel* like a show aimed at kids. Any chance this would be it?

Comment: That's what I was going to say, with equal uncertainty.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt - I admit that I started to write it up as a comment, since generally 1970s prime-time shows were aimed at a general audience; I changed it to a full answer as I thought about my vague recollections of the show, and realized that it could be viewed as being aimed at a younger audience (then again, I remember comments that most TV at that time was aimed at people with an elementary school education).

Comment: that was the show I was looking for, thx